# Django NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.6

I'm making a simple login app in django 1.6 (and python 2.7) and I get an error at the beggining that is not letting me continue.

This is the site's url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import login

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('login.urls', namespace='login')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And this is login/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from login import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^auth/', views.auth, name='auth'),
)
```

This is login/views,py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def auth(request):
    user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    if user is not None:
        # the password verified for the user
        if user.is_active:
            msg = "User is valid, active and authenticated"
        else:
            msg = "The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!"
    else:
        # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
        msg = "The username and password were incorrect."
    return render(request, 'login/authenticate.html', {'MESSAGE': msg})

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'login/login_form.html')
```

I have a form that has this as action:

```
{% url 'login:auth' %}
```

And that's where the problem is, when I try to load the page, I get:

```
Reverse for 'auth' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$auth/']
```

But if I set the url pattern to

```
url(r'', views.auth, name='auth')
```

it works fine, only it sets the action as '/'.

I've been looking all around for an answer and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I tried changing the login url pattern to url(r'^login/$', include('login.urls', namespace='login')), and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is in the way you include the auth URLs in the main one.
 Because you use both ^ and $, only the empty string matches. Drop the $.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy, I was pulling my hair out. Thank you!

Comment: thanks, this answer spared me at least an hour of desperation :)

Comment: They should fix this or create a better error message. I have spent 20 minutes trying to figure out WTF went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had html anchor tag: `<a href="{% url 'url-name' url=someUUID %}">`

in my urls.py

```py
...

path('some_name/<slug:slug>/', views.someDetailView.as_view(), name='url-name'),

...
```

---

### Solution for this:

This: `<a href="{% url 'url-name' someUUID %}">`

Or this: `<a href="{% url 'url-name' slug=someUUID %}">`

> not: `<a href="{% url 'url-name' url=someUUID %}">`

DetailView uses `slug_field = 'someUUIDField'`

---

For some reason I wrote **url** instead of **slug**. Now it works.

Maybe you wrote wrong also, make sure you use `slug=`, if you use `<slug:slug>`.