# Django NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I can't understand what's wrong? I tried to make a detail page of one item, like in example on http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/extend_your_application/index.html
and It doesn't work in my project, but In exercises everything was good.

**Error message:** NoReverseMatch at /

```
Reverse for 'events.views.event_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

**HTML(fragment)**

```
<div class="col-xs-6"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'events.views.event_detail' pk=event.pk %}">Read more</a></div>
         </div>
```

**settings.py**

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

**app urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.events_list),
    url(r'^event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.event_detail),
]
```

**app views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Event

def events_list(request):
    events = Event.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'events/events_list.html', {'events': events})

def event_detail(request, pk):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'events/event_detail.html', {'event': event})
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240680/django-noreversematch)?

Comment: Can you show your root URL conf ?

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

Comment: Well, what URL are you trying to go to? You have it mapped to go to `event/[some_number]`, and the `event_detail` function says it expects an argument (that number, which it uses to look up a pk), but the error says it is getting none, as if you tried to go to `yoursite.com/event` by itself.

Comment: I'm trying to do like  http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/1 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't shown your mysite.urls, but from the error message it looks like you have done something like this:

```
(r'^events/$', include('events.urls')),
```

You need to drop the terminating $, since that means the end of the regex; nothing can match after that. It should be:

```
(r'^events/', include('events.urls')),
```

Note that you should also give your event URLs names, to make it easier to reference:

```
url(r'^$', views.events_list, name='events_list'),
url(r'^event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.event_detail, name='event_detail'),
```

so that you can now do:

```
{% url 'event_detail' pk=event.pk %}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. but in mysite.urls nothing i have only two root:


'from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include("events.urls")),
]'

Comment: Which is exactly what I said. You have a terminating `$` in the line that includes events.urls.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's work! You right problem was in mysite.urls  with '$'