# Django:Getting No reverse Match at /techpedia/(name of my website)

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

While registering new users or logging in new users ,I am getting following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /techpedia/ 
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(u'juit',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This error is only showing up when I am trying to use bootstrap template.Without bootstrap,there is no error
I went through these questions but they are of not much help.
[Django NoReverseMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240680/django-noreversematch) 
[Django NoReverseMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523791/django-noreversematch)

Please tell me what additional information I need to post as I don't have any idea what is causing this error.
Main Url Conf-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from techpedia import views
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self,user):
        return '/techpedia/'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^techpedia/',include('techpedia.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$',MyRegistrationView.as_view(),name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

App Url Conf-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from techpedia import views

urlpatterns=[
        url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
        url(r'^about/$',views.about,name='about'),
        url(r'^add_category/$',views.add_category,name='add_category'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/$',views.add_page,name='add_page'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',views.show_category,name='show_category'),

]
```

Template-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load staticfiles %}

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}">

      <title>techpedia - {% block title %}How to Tango with Django!{% endblock %}</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">techpedia</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
          </li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_category' %}">Add a New Category</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' user.username %}">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'list_profiles' %}">List Profiles</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}?next=/techpedia/">Logout</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register Here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">Type to find a category</li>
                <form>
                    <li class="nav-item"><input class="search-query form-control" type="text"
                        name="suggestion" value="" id="suggestion" />
                    </li>
                </form>
            </ul>
            <hr />
    <div id="cats">
    </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 main">
         {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!--
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <!--
    <script src="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    -->

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/techpedia-ajax.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/techpedia-jquery.js" %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your main URL conf and the relevant app urls along with whatever template or view is raising the error.

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: Where is your `profile` url? You should also look into [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) to keep things neater.