# Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''detail '' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django

[index.html get problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPzH3.png)

[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOyld.png)

my url:
    url(r'^(?P\d+)/$', views.detail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: 1) You have a space at the end of the word: "detail "
2) you need to include in your url a new parameter: name="detail"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code and error message as embedded text, not as external images. Why are you using Django 1.3? That version hasn't been supported for several years, you should upgrade to 1.8.x (LTS) or 1.9.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs

> In order to perform URL reversing, you’ll need to use named URL patterns

For example:

`url(r'^(?P\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')`

And now you able to use `reverse` in python code:

```
reverse('detail', args=(some_number_here))
```

and `url` in templates:

```
{% url 'detail' some_number_here %}
```

And don't forget about namespaces if you use it.