# Reverse for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, migration, url-routing, manage.py

I get this traceback when browsing to https://monajalal.pythonanywhere.com/ and the complete code can be found here https://github.com/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp :

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://monajalal.pythonanywhere.com/
Django Version: 1.9.8
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp']
Server time:    Mon, 18 Jul 2016 20:31:01 -0500
Error during template rendering

In template /home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
1   {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
2   
3   {% block content %}
4       {% for post in posts %}
5           <div class="post">
6               <div class="date">
7                   {{ post.published_date }}
8               </div>
9               <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
10              <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
                              current_app=current_app) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix
                             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)) ...
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'mysite.post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []), another exception occurred:
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/blog/views.py in post_list
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py in render
            template_name, context, request=request, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string
        return template.render(context, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in render
            return self.template.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                    return self._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
                return nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
                        six.reraise(*exc_info) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py in reraise
        raise value ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/monajalal/FirstDjangoApp/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix
                             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)) ...
▶ Local vars
```

I have this in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

And the following in urls.py in blog folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse  
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

Can you please hint what the problem is?

Comment: Probably you have not included app urls into main project urls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to specify the app name in the url namespace:

See this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Or else you need to write your URLs in your html templates like this:

```
    <h1><a href="{% url 'app_name:post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

i.e., you'll have to specify the app name in the url in html while reversing, if you have not specified the app name in your namespace for URLs.

Hope this will resolve the issue.