# NoReverseMatch at / URL

Tags: django, parameters

I am trying to redirect my view to a url with get request parameter but is error.

```
Reverse for 'article-detail-view' with arguments '(u'Django is a powerful web framework that can help you get your Python application or website off the ',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/(?P<slug>\\w+).html$']
```

Error during template rendering

```
{% for article in hot_article_list %}
<li class="list-group-item">
   <span class="hotest-post-title"><a href="
      {% url 'article-detail-view' article.en_title %}
      ">{{article.title}}</a> </span>
   <span class="badge">{{article.view_times}}</span>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Url Pattern:

```
url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index-view'),
url(r'^article/(?P<slug>\w+).html$',
    ArticleView.as_view(), name='article-detail-view')
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: The argument should be `article.slug`, not `article.en_title`: `{% url 'article-detail-view' article.slug %}`

Comment: I edit but error:
Reverse for 'article-detail-view' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/(?P<slug>\\w+).html$']

Comment: Does your `article` model actually have a `slug` field? If not, you cannot use `slug` in the URL configuration for that view.

Comment: Article model: http://pastebin.com/rHzh9xm3

Comment: Your model does not have a field called `slug`, but you are trying to use such a field in the URL for that model. Suggest you read through the documentation on [how to create URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/) to understand how to define them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks you very much.