# Reverse for 's_note' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'note_t': 'note_1 opeth', 'user_name': 'opeth'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-1.9

I have a link to note detail page (s_note) in the user page (username). So as long as I have no entries(notes) in the database for the user the user page renders fine, but as soon as there is a valid note the render fails with the above error and points to ln:6 of user.html.

my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from notes.models import User, Note
from . import views

app_name = 'notes'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='u_index'),
```

my url
        url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='u_signup'),

```
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>[\w\-]+)/$', views.user, name='username'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w\-]+)/(?P<note_t>[\w\-]+)/$', views.note, name='s_note'),
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w\-]+)/(?P<note_t>[\w\-]+)/$', views.note, name='s_note')
]
```

my views

```
def note(request, user_name, note_t):
    nt = Note.objects.get(note_title=note_t)
    return render (request, 'notes/detail.html', {'note': nt})
```

my users.html

```
<h2>Hi! {{ user.user_n }} Your notes are here.</h2>
{% if allnotes %}
    <ul>
    {% for note in allnotes %}

        <li><a href="{% url 's_note' user_name=user.user_n note_t=note.note_title %}">{{ note.note_title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% else %}
    <p>You have no notes yet!</p>
{% endif %}


<form method="post" action""> 
    <table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ NForm }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please try to only include relevant code in your posts.

Comment: You have `app_name = 'notes'` in your urls.py, so you'll need to the namespace in the url tag: `{% url 'notes:s_note' ... %}`

Comment: @Sayse I will keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your url doesn't match for underscores or spaces which your keyword currently contains.

```
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w\-]+)/(?P<note_t>[\w\-]+)/$', views.note, name='s_note'),
```

should be

```
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w\-]+)/(?P<note_t>[\w\-\_\s]+)/$', views.note, name='s_note'),
```

although this isn't much of a solution since most spaces would turn into `%20`'s, you should try to remove any spaces from your keywords and update your regex accordingly.

Comment: I used a workaround by hard-coding the url in the template. I would still like to now about my problem. And thanks for the regex fix. Thank you.

Comment: @ZahirSwayambhoo - The duplicate I linked to provides much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It was a namespacing problem as @Alasdair observed, it sorted with the edit -

```
'{% url 'notes:s_note'...%}'
```

in the template.