# Reverse for 'account_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django, authentication, reverse, login-required

I have a view

```python
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    if request.session.get("pending-token"):
        return redirect("speaker_create_token",
                        request.session["pending-token"])
    return render(request, "dashboard.html")
```

and a row in urls.py

```python
url(r'^dashboard/', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

When I open /dashboard/ with logged user, I see page. My html code is for authentication is

```html
<div>
    <div id="user">

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <snap><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">{{ user.username }}</a> </snap>
            <snap><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a> </snap>
        {% else %}
            <snap><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a> </snap>
            <snap><a href="{% url 'create_user' %}">Sign Up</a> </snap>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to request /dashboard/ without logging I get the error

```html
NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/

Reverse for 'account_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I added LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/' to settings.py, but it does not work.
I saw similar questions, but I still can not understand how to avoid this error.

Comment: None of the code you're showing is trying to use an `account_login` url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I don't use `account_login` url in code, so I can not understand why it notes in the error.

Comment: I think you are being redirected to the `account_login` url because you use `@login_required`, and if you are not logged in Django tries to redirect to your login page.

Comment: So do I need rename `login` to `account_login` in url?