# NoReversMatch for url with parameter

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

So i have a simple model and i want to display list of my recipes. So in urls.py i have following url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^$',
        view=views.RecipeListView.as_view(),
        name='list'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<name>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        view=views.RecipeDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'
    ),
]
```

name is just a name of recipe it can be anything. And than at my list i have following to give url:

```
<div class="list-group">
    {% for recipe in recipe_list %}
      <a href="{% url 'recipes:detail' recipe.name %}" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
      </a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

so i am passing argument of name into detail view but i still get error NoReverseMatch at /recipes/

> Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(u'This is my test recipe',)' and
>   keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   [u'recipes/(?P[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)/$']

And i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Your url's regex doesn't match spaces, nor should it. You should use a slug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a tuple as the name `(u'This is my test recipe',)`, and you are passing it as a positional argument, where your url method expects a keyword argument.

The correct way therefore is:

```
<a href="{% url 'recipes:detail' name=recipe.name[0] %}">
```

Comment: Hmm i tried like that but not really managed to get it working. My name is charfield(255 length). How should i then manage that url is like recipes/this-is-my-recipe ?

Comment: Use a slug field and adjust your regular expression.