# Django - is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to process a form in django/python using the following code.

---

home.html:

```html
<form action="{% url 'home:submit' %}" method='post'>
```

---

views.py:

```py
def submit(request):
    a = request.POST(['initial'])
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {
        'error_message': "returned"
    })
```

---

urls.py:

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^submit/$', views.submit, name='submit')
]
```

when I try to run it in a browser I get the error:

`NoReverseMatch at /home/ u'home' is not a registered namespace`

and another error message indicating a problem with the form.

Comment: have you registered `home` as a namespace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: to register is as a namespace isn't that just by putting 'home.apps.HomeConfig',    in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: It has nothing to do with installed apps

Comment: This is covered in the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names), and, in more detail, in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You should just change you action url in your template:

```
<form action="{% url 'submit' %} "method='post'>
```

---

On the note of url namespaces...

In order to be able to call urls using `home` namespace you should have in your main urls.py file line something like:

for django 1.x:

```
url(r'^', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
```

for django 2.x and 3.x

```
path('', include(('home.urls', 'home'), namespace='home'))
```

Comment: django 3 (and probably django 2): path('someurl', include(('home.urls', 'home'), namespace='home'))

Comment: I don't think you have updated the answer. It is not about url/path, but the 1st parameter in include() must be a tuple. Otherwise you will receive an error: "Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead."

Comment: in django 4.1, path('publisher-polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='publisher-polls')),

Comment: You should also define an app_name variable and set it to the name of your app (as a string) in your app.urls file. Like so, app_name='myapp'. If not, you will run into this error "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported". (Django 4.1)

Comment: In Django 4 you are able to build namespaces through the import of urls.py documents. 
For example in my main url.py I Import app-x.url.py with the Namespace X. 
In the app-x.urls.py I import app-x.specific_urls.py with the namespace Y. 
Lets say in the specific urls.py there is the url named "New".

As Action URL I could then use: href="{% url "X:Y:New" %}"

Maybe you want to add this to your post. 
Best Regards 
Django 4.2

Answer (score 32):

In your main project, open url.py first. Then check, there should be app_name declared at first. If it is not, declare it.

For example, my app name is user info which is declared in url.py

```
app_name = "userinfo"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'home/', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'register/', views.registration, name='register')
]
```

Comment: I want confirm that this works in django 3.0. Then {% url 'userinfo:...' %} can be used. And maybe only this way is possible. Following doesn't work for me: 1) name= or namespace= in project level urls.py, 2) settings in apps.py (maybe I don't know the correct one)

Comment: I need to correct my previous comment: This syntax in main urls.py works too: path('someurl', include(('home.urls', 'home'), namespace='home'))

Comment: This is outdated syntax.

Answer (score 25):

I also faced the same issue.
it is fixed now by adding

```
app_name = "<name of your app>"
```

in app/urls.py

Answer (score 8):

For Django 3.0, if you're handling your urls within the app and using `include` with `path`, in your `project/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(os.getenv('ADMIN_PATH'), admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('my_simple_blog.urls', namespace='my_simple_blog')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

You need to specify `namespace` in `include`.

And then in your `app/urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', registration_view, name='register'),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
]
```

The `app_name` must match the `namespace` you've specified in `project/urls.py`.

Whenever you're referring to these urls, you need to do it like this:

```
{% url 'namespace:name' %}
```

If you're using it with `redirect`:

```
return redirect('namespace:name')
```

Answer (score 8):

For the ***namespace error***,
Make sure you have linked the app's url in the main urls.py file

```
path('app_name/',include('app_name.urls'))
```

also in the urls.py of your app,make sure you mention the app's name as

```
app_name='app_name'
```

Also make sure you have registered the app's name on your installed apps in settings.py

Comment: I followed your steps and it was my problem. Here is exactly what I changed. I share it for those who wanted flesh in blood examples: https://github.com/kasir-barati/go-back-to-score-one-in-learning-django/commit/87a38ea7705d62d147f7485549eb029f45f925c6

Answer (score 2):

As azmirfakkri has said if you're using `redirect`, dont use this `{% url 'namespace:name' %}` syntax, use `return redirect('namespace:name')`.

Comment: `<a href="return redirect('product_detail' product.slug)" class="card-footer-item">View</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Probably 2 things could be a root cause,
in app/urls.py do include as below

```
app_name = 'required_name'
```

and in project urls.py also include the app_name

```
url(r'^required_name/$',views.home,name='required_name'),
```

Check: register app in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 1):

tag name must be unique in the `urls.py` file inside your application package inside the project! it is important for the template tagging to route whats what and where.

now [1] inside the `urls.py` file you need to declare the variable `appName` and give it the unique value. for example `appName = "myApp";` in your case *myHomeApp* and [2] also define the urlpatterns list...

```
urlpatterns = [..., url(r'^submit/$', views.submit, name='submit'), ...];
```

in the html file just change the url tag to:

```
<form action="{% url 'myHomeApp:submit' %}" method='post'>
```

this should sifuce... else just write here and we'll see how to continue on

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake that I always find is when you have some name space in your template,
and in YourApp.url you don't have any name space so if you should use name space add 
in YourApp.url something like this 
    app_name = "blog"

then on your temples make sure you add your name space, 
so you will have some thing like this "assumption errors are coming from `edit.html`"
then on that particular template you will do this
`"{% url 'blog:vote' pk=post.pk %}"` `"{% url 'blog:post_category' category.name %}"`

Answer (score 1):

if you happen to be nesting `include(`s, the namespace compounds, eg. `topappname:appname:viewname`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find this suggestion helpful.

Go to your applications `urls.py` and type this before the urlpatterns:

```
app_name = 'Your app name'
```

Comment: I did find it usefull, although, as it worked, thought I thought it was the point of of creating an AppNAMEConfig role.... would love to have more insight..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who struggled on this error like me: After reading the solutions to this question, I was setting `namespace` in `include` function in a **wrong** urls file. Make sure you are modifying the right urls file. For me it was putting it in the main `url.py` besides `settings.py`. I hope this answer helps anyone who was confused as I was.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> NoReverseMatch at /my_app1/
> 'my_app1' is not a registered namespace

So, I set `account` to `my_app1` in `my_app1/urls.py` as shown below then the error was solved:

```py
# "my_app1/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "my_app1" # Here

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^submit/expense/$', views.submit_expense, name='submit_expense'),
    re_path(r'^submit/income/$', views.submit_income, name='submit_income'),
    re_path(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),

]
```

then open template.html
put for example register register in your HTML tag like this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'register' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
path("", views.index),
path("test/", views.test, name = 'test')]
```

In views.py:

```
def test(request): 
return render(request, "base/test.html")
```

In the template:

```
 href="{% url 'test' %}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using this on my main app's urls so when I use this way This error disappear

In the main folder, where the setting is there, go to urls and
`path("" , include("YourAppName.urls"))`,