# Render a view with arguments from a HTML form

Tags: html, django, templates, render

I would like to query using a HTML form from a template, for example: index.html, and render the data in a different template, results.html.

This was the solution for this same problem but in 2011 (I'm working with the newest version of Django so this is not working anymore)

```
  <form class="body_form"  method="GET" action="{% url 'results' 'var_name' %}" autocomplete="off">

      <input name="var_name" type="text">
```

Post: [Django - is not a registered namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883254/django-is-not-a-registered-namespace/51343021)

Is the syntax in the form field or in the input field right or this is an obsolet? I have the following error when I try this:

```
Reverse for 'results' with arguments '('var_name',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['results']
```

views.py

```
def results(request,var_name):
    context = {'var': var_name,}
    return render(request, 'results.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^results', results, name="results"),
```

Also, can I parse more than 1 variable using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view expects **`var_name`** kwarg in URL, but you haven't provided. So, change your URL config as below,

```
url(r'^results/(?P<var_name>[\w]+)/$', results, name="results"),
```

#### UPDATE-1

to pass the value to URL, change your template

```
action="{% url 'results' var_name=var_name %}"
```

Comment: Thank you! It works properly but in results.html it doesn't display the value of var_name, it display "var_name"

Comment: What else you expect?

Comment: I expect var_name takes the input value

Comment: I got the following error `Reverse for 'results' with keyword arguments '{'var_name': '', }' not found. ` Should I change something in the input name syntax?

Comment: You are missing the value of **`var_name`** in your template context. Thats why the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207561/discussion-between-vicentec-and-arakkal-abu).