# Query data using filter Django/python

Tags: python, django, filter, view, django-urls

I'm pretty new to the Django backend framework. I have been able to easily query data, but now I'm trying to filter that data. When I run the application it will load the landing page and other pages, but when I try to naviagate to the FRReports page I get

"Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\n9177d\webdart\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\webdart\templates\webdart\base.html, error at line 16

'webdart' is not a registered namespace"

Any ideas or guidance?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from webdart.views import AboutView
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


# Use '' to default to the home page
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.landing, name='webdart-landing'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('home/', views.home, name='webdart-home'),

    path('data/', views.data, name='webdart-data'),
    path('data/stationData/', views.data_stationData, name='webdart-data_stationData'),
    path('data/obscura/', views.data_obscura, name='webdart-data_obscura'),
    path('data/tiz/', views.data_tiz, name='webdart-data_tiz'),
    path('data/mcv/', views.data_mcv, name='webdart-data_mcv'),
    path('data/viewer/', views.data_viewer, name='webdart-data_viewer'),
    path('data/multiSiteReport/', views.data_multiSiteReport, name='webdart-data_multiSiteReport'),

    path('antennaBias/', views.documents_antennaBias, name='webdart-documents_antennaBias'),
    path('FRReports/', views.DocRepositoryListView.as_view(), name='webdart-documents_FRReports'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.documents_FRReports.as_view(), name='webdart-documents_FRReports'),
    #path('FRReports/', views.documents_FRReports, name='webdart-documents_FRReports'),
    path('IERSBulletinA/', views.documents_IERSBulletinA, name='webdart-documents_IERSBulletinA'),
```

.
.
.

views.py

```
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from webdart.models import Person, DocRepository 
from webdart.filters import DocRepositoryFilter

class DocRepositoryListView(ListView):
    model = DocRepository
    template_name = 'webdart/FRReports.html'

    def get_context_data (self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = DocRepositoryFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context

class documents_FRReports(DetailView):
   model = DocRepository
   template_name = 'webdart/FRReports.html'

# Create your views here.
def landing(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/landing.html')

def home(request):
    fname = Person.objects.filter(lname='Johnson').filter(fname='Daniel').values('fname').get()
    lname = Person.objects.filter(lname='Johnson').filter(fname='Daniel').values('lname').get()
    phone = Person.objects.filter(lname='Johnson').filter(fname='Daniel').values('phone').get()
    pdfPath = DocRepository.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'webdart/home.html', {'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'phone': phone, 'pdfPath': pdfPath, 'docPath': "C:/oracleas/j2ee/as_wdintAFTB/AintRepository"})
    #return render(request, 'webdart/home.html')

def data(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/data.html')
def data_stationData(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/stationDataHTML.html');
def data_obscura(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/obscuraHTML.html');
def data_tiz(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/tizHTML.html');
def data_mcv(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/mcvHTML.html');
def data_viewer(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/viewerHTML.html');
def data_multiSiteReport(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/multiSiteReport.html');

def documents_antennaBias(request):
     pdfPath = DocRepository.objects.all()
     viewsPerPage = int(13)
     antennaBiasDocs = []

     for file in pdfPath:
         if file.file_location.split("/")[0] == "RTS Range Bias":
            antennaBiasDocs.append(file)

     paginator = Paginator(antennaBiasDocs, 13)
     page = request.GET.get('page')
     contacts = paginator.get_page(page)

     test = "reversed"

     return render(request, 'webdart/antennaBias.html', {'pdfPath': pdfPath,'test': test, 'contacts': contacts, 'viewsPerPage': viewsPerPage, 'antennaBiasDocs': antennaBiasDocs, 'docPath': "C:/oracleas/j2ee/as_wdintAFTB/AintRepository"})

#def documents_FRReports(request):
 #   return render(request, 'webdart/FRReports.html')
```

.
.
.

filters.py

```
    import django_filters
from webdart.models import DocRepository


class DocRepositoryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = DocRepository
        fields = ('file_location',)
```

models.py

```
class DocRepository(models.Model):
    doc_repository_id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    doc_definition = models.ForeignKey(DocDefinition, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_on_doc = models.DateField()
    file_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    destination_src = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    datetimelu = models.DateField()
    useridlu = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_restricted = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_location

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doc_repository'
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{% block title %}WeB DARt{% endblock %}</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'media/wd.png' %}" type="image/x-icon">
          <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <div class="CUI_banner_top">CUI</div>
</head>

<body class="test_margin" {% block data_status %}{% endblock %}>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg_home ">
    <div class="container-fluid ">
      <div class="">
        <div class="row  aaa">
           <a href="{% url 'webdart-home' %}"><img src="{% static 'media/logo.png' %}"></a>
          <!--   WeB DARt
                 <p class="nav_logo ">Web Based Data Analysis and Repository</p>
                 </div>
                 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler bg-light btn-sm py-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="text-dark bg-light h6">Menu</span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-4 nav_center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="">
            <a class="nav-link bg_home px-4 dropdown_hover" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'webdart-home' %}">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link bg_home px-4 dropdown_hover" href="{% url 'webdart-data' %}">Data</a>
          </li>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-4 dropdown show ">
            <a class="text-light nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown_hover" href="dev.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="overlay_documents()">Documents</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu navDrop" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item"  href="{% url 'webdart-documents_antennaBias' %}">Antenna Bias</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item"  href="{% url 'list' %}">F&R Reports</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_IERSBulletinA' %}">IERS Bulletin A</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_IERSBulletinB' %}">IERS Bulletin C</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_NRF' %}">NRF</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_OCNBandwidth' %}">OCN Bandwidth Limits</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_ONDLC' %}">ONDLC</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_ORL' %}">ORL</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_RAPID' %}">RAPID</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-documents_SystemAvail' %}">System Availability</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse px-4 dropdown show">
            <a class="text-light nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown_hover" href="dev.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="overlay_schedule()">Schedule</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu navDrop" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-schedule_launch' %}">Launch Schedule</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-schedule_maintenance' %}">Maintenance Schedule</a>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse px-4 dropdown show test">
            <a class="text-light nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown_hover" href="dev.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="overlay_support()">Support</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu navDrop" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-support_help' %}">Help</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'webdart-support_contact' %}">Contact</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item"href="{% url 'webdart-support_networkRequest' %}">Network Request</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Documents
        
          Antenna Bias
          F&R Reports
          IERS Bulletin A
          IERS Bulletin C
          NRF
          OCN Bandwidth Limits
          ONDLC
          ORL
          RAPID
          System Availability

FRReports.html

```
    {% extends 'webdart/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} WeB DARt - Home {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

          
         <div class="container " >
            <div class="row" >
               <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4 my-5 ">
                  <h1 class="text-decoration-underline">
                  F&R Report Documents
                  <h1>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>


         <div  class="container  shadow  rounded" >
            <div class="row" >
              <table id="customers">
 <tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Upload Date</th>
 </tr>
                  </table>
 </div>
             {{ filter.form }}
 <ul>
     {% for element in filter.qs %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'webdart:detail' element.id %}">a{{ element.file_location }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>


      {% endblock %}
```

Comment: This would help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883254/django-is-not-a-registered-namespace

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error is in your template tag `{% url 'webdart:detail' element.id %}`. I believe that when you use the `{% url %}`, the first argument you give to it is the name of a path in your urlpatterns. If your link is trying to go to your path:

`path('<int:pk>', views.documents_FRReports.as_view(), name='webdart-documents_FRReports')`

Then your template tag should be something like:

`{% url 'webdart-documents_FRReports' element.id %}`

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I wasn't able to get it working with the code originally used. I was able to do filtering within views.py:

```
 """
Views for webdart.
"""

from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from webdart.models import Person, DocRepository 
from webdart.filters import DocRepositoryFilter


def docRepo(request):
     pdfPath = DocRepository.objects.all().order_by('-date_on_doc')
     if request.method == "GET" and len(request.get_full_path().split("?")) > 1 and "page" not in request.get_full_path().split("?")[1]:
         if "choice=date_newToOld" in request.get_full_path().split("?")[1]:
             print(request.get_full_path().split("?"))
             pdfPath = DocRepository.objects.all().order_by('-date_on_doc')
         elif "choice=date_oldtoNew" in request.get_full_path().split("?")[1]:
             print(request.get_full_path().split("?"))
             pdfPath = DocRepository.objects.all().order_by('date_on_doc')
         elif "choice=date_range" in request.get_full_path().split("?")[1]:
             print(request.get_full_path().split("&"))
             greaterThanDate = request.get_full_path().split("&")[1].split("=")[1]
             lessThanDate = request.get_full_path().split("&")[2].split("=")[1]
             print("----------------" + greaterThanDate + lessThanDate)
             pdfPath = DocRepository.objects.all().filter(date_on_doc__lte=lessThanDate)
             pdfPath = pdfPath.filter(date_on_doc__gte=greaterThanDate)
             pdfPath = pdfPath.order_by("-date_on_doc")
     
     viewsPerPage = int(13)
     antennaBiasDocs = []

     for file in pdfPath:
         if file.file_location.split("/")[0] == "F and R Reports":
            antennaBiasDocs.append(file)
     paginator = Paginator(antennaBiasDocs, 13)
     page = request.GET.get('page')
     contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
     return render(request, 'webdart/FRReports.html', {'pdfPath': pdfPath, 'contacts': contacts, 'viewsPerPage': viewsPerPage, 'antennaBiasDocs': antennaBiasDocs, 'docPath': "C:/oracleas/j2ee/as_wdintAFTB/AintRepository"})





# Create your views here.
def landing(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/landing.html')

def home(request):
    fname = Person.objects.filter(lname='Johnson').filter(fname='Daniel').values('fname').get()
    lname = Person.objects.filter(lname='Johnson').filter(fname='Daniel').values('lname').get()
    phone = Person.objects.filter(lname='Johnson').filter(fname='Daniel').values('phone').get()
    pdfPath = DocRepository.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'webdart/home.html', {'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'phone': phone, 'pdfPath': pdfPath, 'docPath': "C:/oracleas/j2ee/as_wdintAFTB/AintRepository"})
    #return render(request, 'webdart/home.html')

def data(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/data.html')
def data_stationData(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/stationDataHTML.html');
def data_obscura(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/obscuraHTML.html');
def data_tiz(request):
    return render(request, 'webdart/tizHTML.html');
```

And then I was able to manipulate that view within the template (I created a template below called document_static.html so I can just include it in the other document pages:

```
{% load static %}



    <div  class="container no_margin" >
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="pagination d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                <span class="step-links ">
                    {% if contacts.has_previous %}
                        <a class="page_button" href="?page=1">&lt&lt</a>
                        <a class="page_button" href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">&lt;</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    <span class="current">
                        Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}
                    </span>
                    {% if contacts.has_next %}
                        <a class="page_button" href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">&gt;</a>
                        <a class="page_button" href="?page={{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}">&gt;&gt;</a>
                    {% endif %}
                  <div class="show filter_div dropup">
            <a class="filter_button" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&equivDD;</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu navDrop filter_drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <p>Sort by:</p>


<form method="GET">

        <input  type="radio" id="date_newToOld" name="choice" value="date_newToOld" checked/>
               <label class="" for="date_newToOld">Date - New to old</label>
                <br />

                <input  type="radio" id="date_oldtoNew" name="choice" value="date_oldtoNew" />
               <label for="date_oldtoNew">Date - Old to new</label>
                <br />
                <input  type="radio" id="date_range" name="choice" value="date_range" />
               <label class="" for="date_range">Date range</label>
                <div class="date_range">
                    <label class="" for="date_range">Start date</label>
                <input type="date" id="start" name="date" value="{% now "Y-m-d" %}" min="2000-01-01" max="{% now "Y-m-d" %}">
                    <label class="" for="date_range">End date</label>
                <input type="date" id="start" name="date" value="{% now "Y-m-d" %}" min="2000-01-01" max="{% now "Y-m-d" %}">

                
               </div>
         </select>
    
                <div class="filter_button_submit_center">
     
                             <input class="filter_button_submit" type="submit" value="Filter">


           
                    </div>
    </form>

            </div>
                      </div>
                        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div  class="container  shadow  rounded" >
        <div class="row" >
            <table id="customers">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Upload Date</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {% for o in contacts %}
                        {% if 0 < forloop.counter and forloop.counter < viewsPerPage %} 
                            <td><a id="open" class="p-0 m-0 fw-bold doc_link">{{ o.title }} </a></td>
                            <td>{{ o.date_on_doc }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="doc_comments_btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#antennaCommentBoxTest{{ forloop.counter0 }} ">Comments</button>
                                <div class="modal fade document_comment_modal" id="antennaCommentBoxTest{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div style="justify-content: center; display: block;" class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="doc_comment_close_btn" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                                    <h3 id="antennaCommentBoxTest{{ forloop.counter0 }}"><b style="font-size: 75%;">{{ o.title }} - Comments</b></h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <p class="doc_comment_feed" id="commentFeed">This document has no comments yet.</p>
                                                    <form>
                                                        <textarea id="newCommentBlock" rows="5" class="doc_comment_textarea" placeholder="Add a Comment" required></textarea>
                                                        <br><button type="button" class="doc_comment_submit_btn" onclick="postComment()">Post</button><br>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                </tr>
                        {% endif %} 
                    {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a document page (IERSBulletinA.html):

```
{% extends 'webdart/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} WeB DARt - Home {% endblock %}
  
{% block content %}

    <div class="container " >
        <div class="row " >
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4 my-5">
                <h1 class="text-decoration-underline">IERS Bulletin A Documents<h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  {% include "webdart/document_static.html" %}

      {% endblock %}
```

And here is urls.py for anybody interested:

```
"""
Definition of urls for webdart.
"""

from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from webdart.views import AboutView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views import View
from .models import DocRepository
from django.http import HttpResponse
admin.autodiscover()



# Use '' to default to the home page
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.landing, name='webdart-landing'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('home/', views.home, name='webdart-home'),

    path('data/', views.data, name='webdart-data'),
    path('data/stationData/', views.data_stationData, name='webdart-data_stationData'),
    path('data/obscura/', views.data_obscura, name='webdart-data_obscura'),
    path('data/tiz/', views.data_tiz, name='webdart-data_tiz'),
    path('data/mcv/', views.data_mcv, name='webdart-data_mcv'),
    path('data/viewer/', views.data_viewer, name='webdart-data_viewer'),
    path('data/multiSiteReport/', views.data_multiSiteReport, name='webdart-data_multiSiteReport'),
    path('antennaBias/', views.documents_antennaBias, name='webdart-documents_antennaBias'),
    path('FRReports/', views.docRepo, name='webdart-documents_FRReports'),
    path('IERSBulletinA/', views.documents_IERSBulletinA, name='webdart-documents_IERSBulletinA'),
    path('IERSBulletinB/', views.documents_IERSBulletinB, name='webdart-documents_IERSBulletinB'),
    path('NRF/', views.documents_NRF, name='webdart-documents_NRF'),
    path('OCNBandwidth/', views.documents_OCNBandwidth, name='webdart-documents_OCNBandwidth'),
    path('ONDLC/', views.documents_ONDLC, name='webdart-documents_ONDLC'),
    path('ORL/', views.documents_ORL, name='webdart-documents_ORL'),
    path('RAPID/', views.documents_RAPID, name='webdart-documents_RAPID'),
    path('SystemAvail/', views.documents_SystemAvail, name='webdart-documents_SystemAvail'),

    path('launch/', views.schedule_launch, name='webdart-schedule_launch'),
    path('maintenance/', views.schedule_maintenance, name='webdart-schedule_maintenance'),

    path('help/', views.support_help, name='webdart-support_help'),
    path('contact/', views.support_contact, name='webdart-support_contact'),
    path('networkRequest/', views.support_networkRequest, name='webdart-support_networkRequest'),

    path('accountDetails/', views.user_accountDetails, name='webdart-user_accountDetails'),
    path('signOut/', views.user_signOut, name='webdart-user_signOut'),
    path('timeOut/', views.user_timeOut, name='webdart-user_timeOut'),
    path('accountRequest/', views.user_accountRequest, name='webdart-user_accountRequest'),

    path('', AboutView.as_view(template_name="data-stationData")),
]
```

And an excerpt from models.py too, because why not:

```
class DocRepository(models.Model):
    doc_repository_id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    doc_definition = models.ForeignKey(DocDefinition, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_on_doc = models.DateField()
    file_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    destination_src = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    datetimelu = models.DateField()
    useridlu = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_restricted = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doc_repository'
```