# Tried to use template inheriteance but getting error all the time

Tags: django, django-templates

[image]

I'm trying to inherit index.html and form.html from base.html. But all the time I'm undone. Please give me a solution. I'm learning Django, new in this field.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove image a post code.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, it is not a problem of the inheritance, you have a `not a registered namespace` error. Some where in your templates you have a link with something like this:

```html
<a href={% url 'new_app:home' %}>Home</a>
```

But you haven't registered `new_app` namespace in your include statement in the `urls.py`

Remover `new_app:` from your template `urls`:

```html
<a href={% url 'home' %}>Home</a>
```

More is here: [Django - is not a registered namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883254/django-is-not-a-registered-namespace)

Comment: I couldn't solve it. Can you help me a bit more????

Comment: @ShishirRehan, please take a loot here: https://github.com/almazkun/django_app, it is working, or push to the GitHub and share the code.