# Tango With Django 1.9 Ch.7 TypeError at /rango/add_page/

Tags: python, django, runtime-error

I am currently at the end of the Tango With Django 1.9's Chapter 7 and working on the exercises.  Upon clicking my "Add a New Page" link on the index.html, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError at /rango/add_page/
>   add_page() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>
> Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/add_page/
>   Django Version:  1.10.5
>   Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:
>
> add_page() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Here are my relevant files:

**views.py**

```
.
.
.
def add_category(request):
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database
            form.save(commit=True)
            # Now that the category is saved
            # We could give a confirmation message
            # But since the most recent category added is on the index page
            # then we can direct the user back to the index page
            return index(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors -
            # just print them to the terminal
            print(form.errors)

    # Will handle the bad form, new form, or no form supplied cases.
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'rango/add_category.html', {'form':form})

def add_page(request, category_name_slug):
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        category = None

    form = PageForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if category:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = category
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                return show_category(request, category_name_slug)
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    context_dict = {'form':form, 'category': category}
    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html',context_dict)
```

**add_page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add a Page</h1>
        <div>

            <!-- <form id = "page_form" method="post" action="/rango/add_page/"> -->
            <form id = "page_form" method="post" action="/rango/category/{{ category }}/add_page/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden }}

                {% endfor %}
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}
                <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
.
.
.
<div>
            <a href="/rango/about/">About Rango</a><br />
            <a href="/rango/add_category/">Add a New Category</a><br />
            <a href="/rango/add_page/">Add a New Page</a><br />
            <img src="{% static "images/rango.jpg" %}" alt="Picture of Rango" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',
        views.show_category, name='show_category'),
]
```

How can I pass in the two arguments to add_page to fix the error?

Comment: Can you add `urls.py` file also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner yes, I'll add it now

Comment: seems like problem is in url pattern `add_page`. You didn't include `category_name_slug` argument to it. Try change it to this: `url(r'^add_page/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.add_page, name='add_page')`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, This caused the following Page not found error:     `Using the URLconf defined in tango_with_django_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^$ [name='index']
    ^rango/ ^$ [name='index']
    ^rango/ ^about/ [name='about']
    ^rango/ ^add_category/$ [name='add_category']
    ^rango/ ^add_page/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$ [name='add_page']
    ^rango/ ^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$ [name='show_category']
    ^admin/
    ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, rango/add_page/, didn't match any of these.
`

Comment: This is because you are trying to open page `rango/add_page` but django waiting something like this `rango/add_page/category_name`. So to make it works you probably can just change link in template to this `<a href="/rango/add_page/{{category}}">Add a New Page</a><br />`. But since I didn't know what you are trying to do exactly I don't know is it fit for you to change urls this way.

Comment: See this link this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it