# django url no reverse match

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass two parameters through the url in django (email,name) it works fine when I am just passing the email through but when I pass the name through as well I get an error (no reverse match) my name contains a space

url pattern

```
url(r'^details/(?P<email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/(?P<name>([\W ]+))/$', details, name="details")
```

full error message

`Reverse for 'password' with arguments '(u'tom@example.com', u'tom')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['details/(?P<email>[\\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/(?P<name>([\\W ]+))/`$

passing variable through to the url

```
{%url 'details' email name %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Comment: I have added the full error message

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error you are getting. When working with multiple variable you can try the following.

```
{%url 'details' email=email name=name %}
```

**Update:**

```
url(r'^details/(?P<email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/(?P<name>([\W ]+))/$', details, name="details")
```

Comment: Can you try if the value you are trying to pass matches the regex properly.

Comment: the value I am passing in the name has a space

Comment: Updated the regex.

Comment: when I copied your updated code in I get a syntax error

Comment: Sorry I copied from yours and only updated the relevant one. You need to update only the regex associated with your name variable.

Comment: I do not get a syntax error anymore, although I still get the no reserve match error

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change

```
(?P<name>(\W+))  # non-alphanumeric
```

to

```
(?P<name>\w+)  # alphanumeric
```

The upper-case version is, one would assume, the exact opposite of what you want to allow for names (and urls in general).

[Python regex syntax docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: What characters are in the name that you are passing?

Comment: You also might want to remove the extra parentheses.