# Reverse for 'post_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 6}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I've been following [djangogirls' tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) to create a blog with django with little to no trouble, but now I'm going on with their [extensions tutorial](https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions) which works on the web application created on the first one, and I'm coming to the error in the title when I try to get to the detail of a given post, which worked alright before.

Here's the error message in full detail

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/6/
>
> Django Version: 1.10.6 Python Version: 3.5.2 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'blog']
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template error: In template
>   /home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/blog/templates/blog/post_detail.html,
>   error at line 14    Reverse for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and
>   keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []   4 :
>       5 :         {% if post.published_date %}    6 : 
>       7 :             {{ post.published_date }}    8 :
>             9 :   {% else %}    10 :      Publish    11 :
>   {% endif %}    12 :   {% if user.is_authenticated %}    13 :      14 :      15 :    {%
>   endif %}    16 :
>
> ## {{ post.title }}
>
> 17 :
>
> {{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}
>
> 18 :         19 : {%
>   endblock %}    20 :
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     42.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/blog/views.py"
>   in post_detail
>     15.     return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py"
>   in render
>     30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py"
>   in render_to_string
>     68.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py"
>   in render
>     66.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     208.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     961.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     961.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     315.                 return nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     961.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     439.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py"
>   in reverse
>     91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix,
>   *args, **kwargs)))
>
> File
>   "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py"
>   in _reverse_with_prefix
>     392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /post/6/ Exception Value: Reverse
>   for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not
>   found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

The site urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views




urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

the blog/urls.py file (blog being the app name)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^drafts/$', views.post_draft_list, name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),


]
```

The offending template blog/templates/blog/post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
            {{ post.published_date }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'blog:post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'blog:post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'blog:post_remove' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and the base template it extends from

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django Girls blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog:post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>     
        <a href="{% url 'blog:post_draft_list' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
        <p class="top-menu">Hello {{ user.username }} <small>(<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>)</small></p>

    {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
        <h1><a href="/">Django Girls Blog</a></h1>


        </div>
        <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried namespacing, I've not changed the regexp in the urls files (i.e. they're the same that did work before), the django version is ok (1.10)... I've read [this other answer about the NoReverseMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but no cigar.

Any ideas on where I may have made it go wrong?

---

Testing int bash:

```
from django.urls import reverse
reverse('blog:post_new') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
"/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py",
line 33, in reverse
    resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)   File "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
line 67, in get_resolver
    urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF   File "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py",
line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)   File "/home/frank/Desarrollo/python/devdjango/djangogirlstut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py",
line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
ROOT_URLCONF, but settings are not configured. You must either define
the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blog` app is under the namespace `blog`. Every reference to a URL to this app should be of the form `namespace:url_name`.

So, you should use a namespace inside the `{% url %}` template tag. You are doing it correctly inside the offending template and you should do the same inside the base template too.

So inside `base.html` (**and anywhere else `blog` urls are involved**):

```
<!-- base.html -->

{% url 'blog:post_new' %}
{% url 'blog:post_draft_list' %}
```

Leave `{% url 'login' %}` and `{% url 'logout' %}` as is. They are not namespaced.

Comment: I just tried it, but no changes. Still the same error message :S

Comment: Have you posted `post_detail.html`?

Comment: yes, it's the "offending template". I'd better make it clearer

Comment: The traceback says inside `post_detail.html` at line 14. But because `post_detail.html` extends `base.html` then it's line 14 of `base.html` which indeed has a call to reverse `post_new`. Namespacing it (inside `base.html`) didn't clear the error?

Comment: No, it didn't. Sorry, I didn't update the template, now it reflects it.

Comment: What about if you write in the `shell`: `from django.urls import reverse` and `reverse('blog:post_new')` ?

Comment: I just added the results. Apparently there's something unconfigured? but this worked ok before, I just don't understand :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138624/discussion-between-nik-m-and-frank).