# I have following messages

Tags: django, python-3.x, view

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/info

Using the URLconf defined in mysites.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^ ^$ [name='index']
^info/
^admin/
```

The current path, info, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('personal.urls')),
    url(r'^info/', include('contacts.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

] #from main hub

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include,url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^info/', views.index,'testme'),
] #from contacts application

Comment: You're missing a trailing slash..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: from django.http import HttpResponse
#
# def contacts(request):
#     return render(request,"personal/contacts.html",{'emailinfo':['if you want to contact me please use email','papa1980@gmail.com']})

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.") ##view

Comment: why I get thous errors?

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43981630/edit) button to update your question with *relevant* information

Comment: where is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you have to use url(r'^$' or url(r'^ in your views and specify only full url in project dispatcher