# Can't create a custom auth model with "if user.is_authenicated" in html

Tags: django, django-authentication

Hi I am trying to make a register link in my html-file. But it only works when I am already logged in.

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Address
    plz = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    ort = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    strasse = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    strnr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    # Kontakt
    mobil = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**forms.py**

I customized the original UserCreationForm to implement to additional fields:

```
class UserCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    --snip--
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 
                  'last_name', 'email', 'mobil', 'plz', 'ort', 
                  'strasse', 'strnr',)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserCreate
    template_url_suffix = '_create_form'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['head'] = 'Account erstellen'
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^user/create/$', views.UserCreate.as_view(), name='user-create'),
```

If I am logged in, I can use the link to create a user instance:

**base.html**

```
 <body>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="{% url 'users:home' %}">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="{% url 'users:user-create' %}">register</a></li>
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <li><a href="{% url 'users:user-detail' user.id %}">Account</a></li>
       {% if user.sportler %}
         <li><a href="{% url 'users:sportler-detail' user.sportler.id %}">Sportler</a></li>
       {% else %}
         <li><a href="{% url 'users:sportler-create' %}">Sportler werden</a></li>
       {% endif %}
 ....
```

> How can I make it work, if one is not logged in???
>
> Error: Reverse for 'user-detail' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P[0-9]+)/detail/$']

Comment: Post you full html or atleast `user-detail` using part

Comment: User-Detail is not supposed to be called. Not when creating or searching for a success_url.

Comment: What is user there? Try request.user instead of it

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing at all to do with it's title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Well, I dont know what to look for. When I am logged in with a user. I can load the "user-create"-view and create a new user. I can log out and then log in with the new user. If I am not logged in, I get the above error. I dont get why the system even tries to load the user-detail. I also removed any decorators.

Comment: I tried 'request.user.id' instead of user.id  in<a href="{% url 'users:user-detail' user.id %}">Account</a> - Reverse for 'user-detail' with arguments '(None,)' not found. None is because nobody is logged in. I dont get why it wants to load the user-detail at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a back-link in my creation form. Call me morron.

```
<a href="{% url 'users:user-detail' user.id %}"><button>Zurück</button></a>
```

Edited it to `<a href="{% url 'users:home' %}"><button>Zurück</button></a>` and it works...