# Django NoReverseMatch and POST URL error

Tags: python, django, url

I am facing 2 issues `NoReverseMatch`  and `APPEND_SLASH` .

Issue #1. APPEND_SLASH

Detail.html

```
<form action="update-entry" method="post">
/* if I add '/' at the end of update-entry, it works fine. */
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

When I click on the Edit button, I get the error below,

> ```
> You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have 
> APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining 
> POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/genericviews/1/update-
> entry/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django 
> settings.
> ```

This is the URL generated:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/genericviews/1/update-entry

I know URL should end with '/'.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailsView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^makeentry$', views.makeentry, name='makeentry'),
url(r'^static/$', views.StaticView.as_view()),


url(r'^new-entry/$', views.MakeEntryView.as_view(), name='new-entry'),

url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update-entry/$', views.UpdateEntryView.as_view(), name='update-entry'),


]
```

My confusion is why URL is not generating '/' at the end. Above URL pattern seems correct to me.

Issue #2 NoReverseMatch

When I try to change the hardcoded URL, I get the error below,

```
NoReverseMatch at /genericviews/1/
Reverse for 'update-entry' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' 
not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['genericviews/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update-
entry/$']
```

Detail.html

```
<form action="{% url 'genericviews:update-entry' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Delete Product"> 
</form>
```

tried link as well,

```
{#<a href="{% url 'genericviews:update-entry' %}">Edit</a>#}
```

When I click on any item from the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/genericviews/`,
it takes me to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/genericviews/1/`
And this is where it shows error.

I checked other answers, however, couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set `APPEND_SLASH` in `settings.py` file to True

Comment: you should raise each issue as separate questions, although research your questions first, there are multiple duplicates for the no reverse match error (and probably this one)

Comment: Instead of saying "please guide", which could be taken as inconsiderate, you should try saying "thank you for your time" or "any help would be appreciated."

Comment: @Sayse I found a couple of questions related no reverse, but they were not related to this one.

Comment: @marcusshep thank you :)

Comment: [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it) - They're all related, the error message makes it clear that you're not providing a pk.

Comment: @Sayse tried providing a pk.
Error:   Reverse for 'update-entry' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not adding a slash because you haven't asked it to. You've hard-coded the relative URL of "update-entry", so that's what it will use.

When you do try and use the url tag, you get the error because you haven't passed the arguments it needs to generate that URL. Assuming you have the object in your template context as `object`, you would do:

```
{% url 'genericviews:update-entry' pk=object.pk %}
```

Comment: I tried changing the URL with above one, but its not working.

Comment: Error: Reverse for 'update-entry' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Because now you've missed off the 'genericviews:' namespace prefix. That part wasn't wrong before.