# Django - Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, paypal, render

I'm working on my project for a course and I'm totally stuck right now. I'm creating a website to sell products through paypal and the paypal return/cancel pages are not rendering properly. I've followed the examples in my lessons and checked the code a hundred times but obviously there is something I'm missing.

I'm getting an error when I go to products, click buy now, login to paypal and then either cancel the purchase or buy the product and return to merchant's page.
paypal_return.html and paypal_cancel.html are 2 templates saved under templates/paypal/

Can anybody see what I'm missing?

Here you can see the full code https://github.com/IreneG5/spss_online

Traceback

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/paypal-cancel/

Django Version: 1.11.4
Python Version: 2.7.12
```

Installed Applications:

```
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_forms_bootstrap',
 'paypal.standard.ipn',
 'home',
 'accounts',
 'paypal_store',
 'products']
```

Installed Middleware:

```
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Template error:

```
In template C:\Users\irene\Documents\Full-Stack-Developer\Stream3\Project\spss_online\templates\base.html, error at line 10
   Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.   1 : {% load staticfiles %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <html lang="en">
   4 : <head>
   5 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   6 :     <title>Buy SPSS Online</title>
   7 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   8 :     <meta name="description" content="">
   9 :     <meta name="author" content="">
   10 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
   11 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
   12 : 
   13 : 
   14 : </head>
   15 : <body>
   16 : <div class="container">
   17 :     <div class='container-fluid'>
   18 :         <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   19 :             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
   20 :                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\irene\Documents\Full-Stack-Developer\Stream3\Project\spss_online\paypal_store\views.py" in paypal_cancel
  15.     return render(request, 'paypal/paypal_cancel.html', args)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  458.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Users\irene\virtualenv\spss_online_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /paypal-cancel/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: You have to use with app name eg. {% url 'core:home' %} here core is the name of the app and home the view name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

When you use the url tag you should use quotes for string literals, for example:

```
{% url 'products' %}
```

At the moment `product` is treated like a variable and evaluates to `''` in the error message.

Comment: That was it. I added the quotes in the template and the name='products' in urls.py and it works now. 
Thanks Alasdair!

Comment: This may also be the correct answer for the question of "why does a legacy django form that submits to the same page no longer work after upgrading django". I make this comment so Google can help others find the answer.

Answer (score 53):

1. The syntax for specifying url is `{% url namespace:url_name %}`. So, check if you have added the `app_name` in urls.py.
2. In my case, I had misspelled the url_name. The urls.py had the following content `path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='question_detail')` whereas the index.html file had the following entry `<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>`. Notice the incorrect name.

Comment: In my case, I added the app_name to my urls.py and then missed to include the "namespace:" prefix. So thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: This is so far one of the best answers I found. No one seems to mention `{% url 'namespace:url_name' %}` - People respond with `{%url  'url_name' %}`

Comment: Dude thanks for pointing that out - incidentally, I feel there may be a mistake in the Django official tutorial? THey also omit the namespace prefix...

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that there is no space between namespace and url_name. In my case, space was the error

Answer (score 29):

I was receiving the same error when not specifying the `app` name before pattern name. 
In my case:

`app-name` : Blog

`pattern-name` : post-delete

`reverse_lazy('Blog:post-delete')`  worked.

Comment: Where do you add `reverse_lazy('Blog:post-delete')`?

Comment: @DerekPK E.g, while assigning to `success_url` or in `get_success_url` method.

Answer (score 11):

Add store name to template like `{% url 'app_name:url_name' %}`

App_name = store

In urls.py,
`path('search', views.searched, name="searched"),`

`<form action="{% url 'store:searched' %}" method="POST">`

Answer (score 9):

You can use one of these.

If you did not (app_name)
This is the solution

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
]
```

in template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"></a>
```

If you did (app_name)
This is the solution

in urls.py

```
app_name = 'Blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
]
```

in template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'Blog:dashboard' %}"></a>
```

Comment: man, idk how many post did I read on how reverse works, and this post of yours is literally help me finally understanding it. THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Specify `app_name` in the **urls.py** file of an app and use this app_name along with the string literal view name of the url in templates:

```
syntax --> {% url 'app_name:urlname' %}

app_name = "demo".   # right above url patterns in app
url_patterns = [
('login/', views.login, name = 'login')
]

<a href="{% url 'demo:login' %}".  # Use this in templatep
```

**Note:** use the `app_name` right above the `url_patterns` in urls.py file.

Answer (score 6):

Fix `urlpatterns` in urls.py file

For example, my app name is "simulator",

My URL pattern for `login` and `logout` looks like

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', simulator.views.login_view, name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', simulator.views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    ...
    ...

]
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, what I did was a mistake in the url tag in the respective template. So, in my url tag I had something like

{% url 'polls:details' question.id %}

while in the views, I had written something like:

def details(request, question_id):
    code here

So, the first thing you might wanna check is whether things are spelled as they shoould be. The next thing then you can do is as the people above have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this error occurred because I forgot to add `app_name` along with `url_name`.
Below is my app `urls.py`

```py
    app_name = "wikis"
    urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.index, name="index"),
        path("wiki/<str:name>", views.get_page, name="get_page"),
       ]
```

Below is my function's return statement where I forgot to put `app_name` in reverse URL

```py
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("get_page", kwargs={'name':title}))
```

Correct code would be

```py
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("wikis:get_page", kwargs={'name':title}))
```

Comment: This answer is very close to how I fixed. I was using a different name in the path function so it was not matching. But it worked after I used the correct path name in the Reverse function without the app name. So from above explanation this worked for me
<code> return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("get_page", kwargs={'name':title}))</code>

Answer (score 2):

*Always make sure when you use HttpResponseRedirect and reverse, the name you specify inside reverse is the same name you gave to your path inside urls.py

Thats the problem i had and i found out through trial and error*

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue while testing, for me it was caused when url was empty in html

```
<td><a href="{% url '' test.id %}"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
```

So after I changed it by putting the url name:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'task_delete' test.id %}"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I don't put namespace_name in the url tag ex: `{% url 'url_name or pattern name' %}.`
you have to specify the namespace_name like: `{% url 'namespace_name:url_name or pattern name' %}.`

**Explanation:** In project **urls.py** `path('', include('blog.urls',namespace='blog')),` and in app's **urls.py** you have to specify the app_name. like `app_name = 'blog'`. namespace_name is the app_name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you forget to add the app url in the project url

**Example:**
*Project/urls.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]
```

and you have a *store/urls.py*

so if you have html code in *store/templates/store*
and you want to add in *app/templates/app* an a tag with the url to an html code in *store/templates/store*

You would have to include the store/urls.py in *Project/urls.py*

*Project/urls.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('', include('store.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading this for past two days to compare mine to see why it didn't work. it turns out a space between ":" matters:
mine had a **space** between ":" and "index":

```
<a href="{% url 'namespace: index' %}">Home</a>
```

thought this worth mentioning in case someone like me scratching their heads in the future:
No space around the colon, or anywhere before or after "namespace" and "index"

Answer (score 1):

**It is like that you have written wrong pattern of url in template file. Such that you write**

instead {% url 'claim:cashless_opd_send_otp' %}

Comment: {% url 'cashless_opd/send_otp' %} to {% url 'view:route_name' %} example:  {% url 'claim:cashless_opd_send_otp' %}

Answer (score 0):

If you dont define name in the path field, usually the error will come.
e.g.: `path('crud/',ABC.as_view(),name="crud")`

Comment: This is not the answer. Edit it in order to the question or write it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Give the same name in urls.py

```
 path('detail/<int:id>', views.detail, name="detail"),
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about your suggestion? Why will it help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred due to a `mismatched` url name. e.g,

```
<form action="{% url 'test-view' %}" method="POST">
```

urls.py

```
path("test/", views.test, name='test-view'),
```

Answer (score 0):

*Always make sure when you use HttpResponseRedirect and reverse, the name you specify inside reverse is the same name you gave to your path inside urls.py

'return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
path("index/",views.index,name="index")'

Thats the problem i had and i found out through trial and error*

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. The mistake was I declared same name for multiple  urlpatterns.

```
 path('file', views.sender, name='sender'),
```

Here the name should be different and unique for different url.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say in your template home.html you are having a form that does a POST request, like:

```
<form id="form_id" action = "{% url 'home' %}" method = "post" > .. </form>
```

In your urls.py you have

```
url(r'^$', views.home_view, name='home')
```

in your view, you can check the passed data from template like this.

```
def home_view(request): print(request.POST)
```

it is important in urls.py to declare a **name='home'** and on your action part on the form to include this url **action = "{% url 'home' %}"**

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is

```
 path('detail/', views.detail, name="This_is_the_solution"),
```

you have to give the name value to the url,

```
<a href="{% url 'This_is_the_solution' %}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Some cases:
You should not forgot to load the home page or base page by using
eg:
`{%extends "app_name/web_page.html"%>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the solutions shared by various folks.
I had the same issue when I was trying to use `url` template of Django
Below is the scenario mentioned below:

We have an app with name `base` and inside that we have `base/urls.py` file. Below are the entries we have in `base/urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name='home'),
    path("room/<str:pk>/", views.room, name='room')
]
```

When I was trying to access these url pattern as below in our template, we were getting the error

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'room' room.id %}">{{ room.id }}</a>
        - {{ room.name }}
    </p>
</div>
```

The issue occurs due to the way we have defined the `url` template.
To resolve this issue, I simply need to prefix the app name as below

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'base:room' room.id %}">{{ room.id }}</a>
        - {{ room.name }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The common error that I have found is when you forget to define
your URL in `yourapp/urls.py`.

Answer (score -1):

On line 10 there's a space between `s` and `t`. It should be one word: `stylesheet`.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should that additional space trigger the given error?

Answer (score -1):

appname=demo
url=/student

**href="{% url 'demo:student' %}"**

Make Sure you should not have space before or after : (colon)