# why showing Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '(27,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['del/$']....?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

i was trying to delete a record in model, can't query the object by id

my code

Html :

```
<a href="{% url 'todo:delete' todo.id %}">DELETE</a>
```

url.py :

```
url(r"^del/$" ,views.DeleteContent,name="delete"),
```

views.py :

```
def DeleteContent(request,u_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('accounts:login')
    #todo=ToDo.objects.all()
    todo=ToDo.object.filter(u_id=id)
    todo.delete()
    return render(request,"index.html")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

change your url structure to this

```
url(r"^del/(?P<u_id>\d+)/$" ,views.DeleteContent,name="delete"),
```