# Error: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

Django version: `1.11.4`
Python: `3.6.1`

I want to add a line to my html file:

```
<a class="pure-button" href="{% url 'detail' id=post.id %}">Read More </a>
```

views.py:

```
def detail(request, id):
    try:
        post = Article.objects.get(id=int(id))
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post':post})
```

url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
import article.views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^(\d+)', article.views.detail),
    url(r'^', article.views.home),
]
```

I met the following errors:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Who can help me? Many thanks！

Comment: Well the errors correct... you don't have a url named detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', article.views.detail, name='detail'),
```

change the url of your details view to the upper one