# NoReverseMatch Django favorite

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to this Django stuff and i'm getting a NoReverseMatch at /cityinfo/

Exception Value:

```
Reverse for 'user_favorites' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cityinfo/(?P<fav_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

basically what i'm trying to do is get all the users Favorited posts and display them when the user clicks on the favorite navigation link in base.html

## base.html

```
                <li class="#">
                    <a href="{% url 'cityinfo:user_favorites' favorites.id %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>&nbsp; Favourites
                    </a>
                </li>
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<fav_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.user_favorites, name="user_favorites"),
```

## views.py

```
def user_favorites(request, fav_id):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request, 'cityinfo/login.html')
else:
    favorites = get_object_or_404(user_favourite_spot, id=fav_id)
    context = {
        "favorites": favorites
    }
    return render(request, 'cityinfo/user_favorites.html', context)
```

appreciate your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to call it from a different view, your `favorites` doesn't exist in the current context ( or its id is None)

Answer (score 4):

You have no `fav_id` in your template's context, so when the template renders the variable, it's rendering to `''`.

Change your `url` tag to `{% url 'cityinfo:user_favorites' favourites.id %}`

Comment: Since the URL pattern expects a kwarg called fav_id, is it necessary to explicitly provide that part like so? `<a href="{% url 'cityinfo:user_favorites' fav_id = favorites.id %}">`

Comment: @souldeux No, named capturing groups can be passed as positional arguments when reversing.

Comment: thanks for you help, however im still getting the same error