# Django url resolver

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-urls

On this line in the template:

```
{% url object|smart_admin_urlname:'change' object.pk %}
```

I got:

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'exercises_exercise_change' with arguments '(3,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

> exercises/admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import site, ModelAdmin

class ExerciseAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['apply_tag', 'show', 'hide']
    list_filter = ['exercise_set', 'visible', 'exercise_set']
    list_display = ['short_title', 'visible', 'exercise_set']
    # ommited custom functions and irrelavent parameters

class PythonExerciseAdmin(ExerciseAdmin):
    form = PythonExerciseAdminForm

class SqlExerciseAdmin(ExerciseAdmin):
    form = SqlExerciseAdminForm

site.register(PythonExercise, PythonExerciseAdmin)
site.register(SqlExercise, SqlExerciseAdmin)
```

The working url in administration site should look like:

> http://127.0.0.1/admin/exercises/pythonexercise/3/
>   http://127.0.0.1/admin/exercises/sqlexercise/4/

I'm not sure where to look, or change to fix this bug.

---

Thank you @Sandeep Balagopal! 
Why didn't I think of `grep -rl "smart_admin_urlname" .` silly me.

> common/templatetags/common_tags.py

```
@register.filter
def smart_admin_urlname(obj, view_name):
    return u'admin:{0}_{1}_{2}'.format(obj._meta.app_label,
                                       obj._meta.model_name, view_name)
```

---

> exercises/models.py

```
class Exercise(Model):
    # ommited custom parameters and functions

class PythonExercise(Exercise):
    exercise_type = Constant.PYTHON
    # ommited custom parameters 

class SqlExercise(Exercise):
    exercise_type = Constant.SQL
```

---

Adding the following line fixed the link, but this is not what I want to do...it makes the admin site show the `Exercise` class.

```
site.register(Exercise, ExerciseAdmin)
```

---

Tried, but did not make any difference:

> exercises/forms.py

```
def get_admin_form(exercise_model=PythonExercise,exercise_type=Constant.PYTHON):
    class ExerciseAdminForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = exercise_model
            fields = '__all__'

        def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
            super(ExerciseAdminForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.fields['starter_code'].widget = _make_language_mode(exercise_type=exercise_type)
            if exercise_type == Constant.PYTHON:
                # omitted
    print('DEBUG:model = ',ExerciseAdminForm.__dict__['_meta'].__dict__['model'] )               
    return ExerciseAdminForm
```

Debug message shows:

```
('DEBUG:model = ', <class 'exercises.models.PythonExercise'>)
('DEBUG:model = ', <class 'exercises.models.SqlExercise'>)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please show your smart_admin_urlname filter as well.

Comment: I don't know where to find this 'smart' admin...

Comment: So the smart_admin_urlname is a custom template filter. It must be defined somewhere in the templatetags/ directory.

Comment: You haven't shown how you have registered your models with your model admin classes. Your `smart_admin_urlname` looks as if it is duplicating the functionality of the [`admin_urlname`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) tag in the admin app.

Comment: You haven't registered a model admin for the `Excercise` model, so `{% url object|smart_admin_urlname:'change' object.pk %}` isn't going to work if `object` is an `Exercise` instance. You need to use a `PythonExercise` or `SqlExercise` instance.