# NoReverseMatch at /app/index I already URL

Tags: python, django

I got an error,NoReverseMatch at /app/index.
I wrote in views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def test1(request):
    return render(request, 'test1.html')

def test2(request):
    return render(request, 'test2.html')
```

in urls.py

```
app_name = "app"
urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.index,name='index'),
    path('test1', views.test1,name='test1'),
    path('test2', views.test2,name='test2'),
]
```

in index.html

```
    <tr>

        <td align="center ">
            <a class="test1" href="{% url 'test1' %} ">test1</a>
        </td>

        <td align="center ">
            <a class="test2" href="{% url 'test2' %} ">test2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

When I access index method,
NoReverseMatch at /app/index
Reverse for 'test1' not found. 'test1' is not a valid view function or pattern name.  error happens.
I rewrote

```
<a class="test1" href="{% url 'app:test1' %} ">test1</a>
```

but same error happens.
I really cannot understand why I got this error.I already test1&test2 url.How should I fix this?
Traceback says
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrmymyapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrmymyapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/Downloads/mymyapp/myapp/views.py", line 166, in kenshinresults
    return render(request, 'index.html')
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 447, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_mymyapp=current_mymyapp)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 632, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
```

My base url is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('app/', include('app.urls')),

 ]
```

Comment: Hope this SO Answer would help you to solve the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Please provide the console output.

Comment: @abybaddi009 I added my Traceback

Comment: Can you share your base urls?

Comment: @vishes_shell I added my base urls.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,
in `views.py`

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/index.html')

def test1(request):
    return render(request, 'app/test1.html')

def test2(request):
    return render(request, 'app/test2.html')
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but it's worth a try to change your imports and urlpatterns as it presented at [`django.urls` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/):

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  # note that its `path` not `url`
    path('app/', include('app.urls')),  # note that its `path` not `url`
]
```