# NoReverseMatch at /admin/pinterest/pinner/add/

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a project "pinterest clone". I am following the bellow link - https://github.com/sobriquette/pinclone . When I try to add a pinner I am getting this error - "NoReverseMatch at /admin/pinterest/pinner/add/" . I don't understand what's the problem. Please help me to find out.

This is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import uuid

from django.db import models
import django.utils.encoding

class Pinner(models.Model):
    pinner_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=255)
    avatar = models.URLField(blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def print_attr(self):
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            if '__' not in k:
                print("{}: {}".format(k, v))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Board(models.Model):
    board_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pinner = models.ForeignKey(Pinner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.URLField()

    def print_arrt(self):
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            if '__' not in k:
                print("{}: {}".format(k, v))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Pin(models.Model):
    pin_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=255)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    link_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def print_attr(self):
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            if '__' not in k:
                print("{}: {}".format(k, v))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Image(models.Model):
    image_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=255)
    pin = models.ForeignKey(Pin, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    def print_attr(self):
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            if '__' not in k:
                print("{}: {}".format(k, v))

    def __self__(self):
        return self.url
```

and this is the admin.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pinner
from .models import Board
from .models import Pin
from .models import Image

admin.site.register(Pinner)
admin.site.register(Board)
admin.site.register(Pin)
admin.site.register(Image)
```

Comment: Can you please post your urls.py and your views.py? [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: whats the URL you are visitng when you see this error?

Comment: this is my urls.py
`from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^pinterest/', include('pinterest.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]`
and this is the views.py
`from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Pin

def index(request):
 contex = {'pins_list': Pin.objects.all()}
 return render(request, 'pinterest/index.html', contex)`

Comment: when I try to add new pinner the url is
(http://localhost:8000/admin/pinterest/pinner/add/) @Walucas

Comment: whats your django version?

Comment: django version 1.11.20 @Walucas