# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I am beginner in django, I have started the course of it last week and got stuck into this error from last two days. Seeking for the help to get out from that mess I have made.

I am not able to open the dashboard of my site don't know what has happened.
I have been searching for this from last two days. Still haven't got anything.

Environment:

```
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    Django Version: 2.2.3
    Python Version: 3.7.3
    Installed Applications:
    ['pages.apps.PagesConfig',
     'listings.apps.ListingsConfig',
     'realtors.apps.RealtorsConfig',
     'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.humanize']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Template error:

```
    In template C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\webproject\Template\partials\_nav.html, error at line 50
       Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
       40 : 
       41 :         <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       42 :           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       43 :             <li
       44 :             {% if 'dashboard' in request.path %}
       45 :               class="nav-item active mr-3"
       46 :             {% else %}
       47 :               class="nav-item mr-3"
       48 :             {% endif %}
       49 :             >
       50 :               <a class="nav-link" href=" {% url 'dashboard' %} ">
       51 :                 Welcome {{ user.username }}, "Dashboard" </a>
       52 :             </li>
       53 :             <li class="nav-item mr-3" >
       54 :               <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}" class="nav-link">
       55 :                 <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
       56 :               </a>
       57 :               <form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="POST" id="logout">
       58 :                 {% csrf_token %}
       59 :                 <input type="hidden">
       60 :               </form>
```

Traceback:

```
    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\webproject\pages\views.py" in index
      21.     return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
      36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
      62.     return template.render(context, request)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
      61.             return self.template.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      171.                     return self._render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
      163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
      904.             return self.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
      150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
      163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
      904.             return self.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
      188.             return template.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      173.                 return self._render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
      163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
      904.             return self.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
      309.                 return nodelist.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
      904.             return self.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
      443.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
      90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

    File "C:\Users\kamal jeet singh\wproject\kt\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
      668.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('listings/', include('listings.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you share the `urls.py` and the view that is triggered by `/`?

Comment: We need your `urls.py` and views to point at error. You haven't set that name "dashboard" to a corresponding url regex and a view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38390177/1216776

Comment: Please, share your `urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you link to `{% url 'dashboard' %}`, however in your `urls.py` you don't have a route for it. You can add it like this:

```
 path('dashboard/', /* dashboard view here */, name='dashboard'),
```

Alternatively, if you have a `dashboard` app:

```
 path('dashboard/', include('pages.urls'), name='dashboard'),
```