# NoReverseMatch error. My URL is not a valid view function or pattern name despite having a URL and View associated with it

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a form with an input button group that redirects the user to another URL given the button they pushed. I am currently receiving a NoReverseMatch when I don't think I should be.

I went through the top answer of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but don't think those apply to me.

The form in index.html:

```html
    <form action="/main/community/" method="get">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value='Comm1'>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value='Comm2'>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value='Comm3'>
    </div>
    </form>
```

My URL's:

```py
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Index, name='index'),
    path('community/', views.Community, name='community'),
    path('community/choice',views.CommView, name='CommView'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

My views:

```py
def Community(request):
    try:
        pass
    except (KeyError):
        pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('community/choice'))

def CommView(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test success!.")
```

When I press the buttons no redirect occurs. When I manually input the URL of `/community/choice/` I receive the following error:

`NoReverseMatch` at `/main/community/`

`Reverse for 'community/choice' not found. 'community/choice' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: PS: I know my form isn't passing any information to then next URL at the moment - I'm just trying to test the redirect.

Comment: Use the url _name_, not the actual _url pattern_, as the argument to `reverse()`.  i.e. you want `reverse('commView')`.

Comment: @JohnGordon that didn't work either. I received the same error but this time it was: NoReverseMatch at /main/community/

Reverse for 'CommView' not found. 'CommView' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try `main:CommView` . App_name:view_name like you define in urls.py

In my project i use like this

```
return reverse('blog:article_detail', kwargs={
            'article_id': self.id,
            'title': self.title
        })
```