# How to solve NoReverseMatch?

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

[Refer here for traceback****](http://dpaste.com/1YMEFW9)django throwing the error like this. Exception Value:Reverse for 'movie_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['movie\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    {{object.first_name}} - {{object.last_name}}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h1> {{object}} </h1>
    <h2>Actor</h2>
    <ul>
            <p>hello</p>
        {% for role in object.role_set.all %}
        
            <li>
                <a href="{%  url 'core:movie_details' role.movie.id %}">{{role.movie}} </a>
            </li>
        {%  endfor %}
    </ul>

    <h2>Writer</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for movie in objects.writing_credits.all %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'core:movie_details' movi.id %}"> {{movie}} </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <h2>Director</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for movie in object.directed.all %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'core:movie_details' movi.id %}"> {{movie}} </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

### codes in model.py

```
from django.db import models

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def all_with_prefetch_movies(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.prefetch_related('directed','writing_credits','roll_set__movie')

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    born = models.DateField()
    died = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

    objects = PersonManager()
```

### Codes in views.py

```
class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.all_with_prefetch_persons()


class PersonDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all_with_prefetch_movies()
```

### url mapping in urls.py

**url pattern mentioned bellow**

```js
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies/', MovieList.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
    path('movie/<int:pk>/', MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie_details'),
    path('person/<int:pk>/', PersonDetail.as_view(), name='person_details'),
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Sanjay If you tried other SO answers and still you get error, then you should reproduce your code with error in question or else, try looking for already available SO answers that might help you

Comment: Can please look at the problem now. I added quite codes and explination for the problem