# NoReverseMatch at /update Reverse for 'update_profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['updateprofile/(?P<profile_pk>[^/]+)$']

Tags: html, django

## views.py

```
def form_demo_update(request,profile_pk):
profile = get_object_or_404(Createdemo,pk=profile_pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = Form_demo(request.POST or None, instance=profile)
```

# success_url = reverse_lazy('profile_update')
    #success_msg = 'Ok'

```
if form.is_valid():
    #instance=form.save(commit=False)
    form.save()
    return redirect('/')
context={
    'form':form,
    'profile':profile,
}
return render(request,'travel_form.html',context)
```

## urls.py

```
path('updateprofile/<profile_pk>',views.form_demo_update,name='update_profile'),
```

## update.html

```
<form action="{%url 'update_profile' profile.pk %}" method="post">
             {% csrf_token %}
                 {{form}}                   
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />

        </form>
```

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)