# I am trying to redirect my in my django app but its giving me NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, python-3.7, django-urls

I expect code to redirect to url with name=home. But I am getting an error.

code snippet from my views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Signup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            new_user = User(name=name, email=email)
            new_user.save()
            return redirect('home')
```

code snippet from my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')]
```

Error I am getting is:
NoReverseMatch at /signup/
Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

The function redirect takes a view-name, or url as argument, not the name of a path.
E.g. `return redirect('some-view-name')`

However, you want to use the path name you have specified you can use `reverse()`.

```
from django.urls import reverse
return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

Comment: i did the same thing sir... instead of some-view-name i passed home which i have specified as a view name in urls.py

Comment: i tried your solution but got this error  - Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.