# Something's Wrong When I Try to Register on my Website

Tags: python, django, registration, django-registration, vs-web-site-project

I have been trying to make my Django website. I need to register to my website to test if once I'm logged in, I could log out. But when I try to log in, the log in page does not pop up. Some page pops up instead, and this is what the terminal says:

```
Internal Server Error: /testissue/user_login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benic\Desktop\My Stuff\Programming\Files\Websites\Django Websites\Learning Web Development\Back-End\Django\Django Level 5\DjangoProjectLevel5\DjangoAppLevel5\views.py", line 73, in user_login
    return render(request, 'DjangoAppLevel5/login.html', {})
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\benic\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'DjangoAppLevel5/user_login' not found. 'DjangoAppLevel5/user_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Can somebody please assist me? If you need me to post a file, ask me, please.

Comment: Take a look here for [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it) on `NoReverseMatch` errror in `Django`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I've read your links, and they don't seem to be the reason my website is not working (they're also the same link).