# NoReverseMatch problem with my tutorial for Django

Tags: python, django, reverse, django-urls

Going through the Django Tutorial in `Python` Crash Course and am facing a wall. The error I get is
'Reverse for 'topic' with arguments `'('',)'` not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['topics/(?P<topic_id>\\d+)/$']'`.

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import URL


from . import views


urlpatterns = [
# the actual url patter is a call to the url () function, which takes three arguments
# Home page
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

#Show all topics 
url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),

# Detail page for a single topic
url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),

]

app_name= 'learning_logs'
```

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

```
from .models import Topic

def index(request):
"""The home page for Learning Log"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
"""Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics' :  topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

topic.html
{%extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

```
{%block content%}
<p>Topic: {{topic}}</p>
<p>Entries:</p>
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
            <p>{{entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i'}}</p>
            <p>{{entry.text| linebreaks}}</p>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>
            There are no entries for this topic yet.
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{%endblock content%}
```

I've read through some of the `Django` documentation but I'm not comprehending enough to solve this problem on my own. If I need to add some more code to help please let me know. All help is really appreciated.

Edit:
Topics.html

```
{%extends 'learning_logs/base.html'%}

{% block content%}

<p>Topics</p>
<ul>
    {%for topic in topics%}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic_id%}">{{topic}}</a>
        </li>
    {%empty%}
        <li>No topics have been added yet</li>
    {%endfor%}
</ul>

{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: I'm the author of PCC. You're working from a fairly outdated version of the first edition of the book. Later copies of the first edition used the `path()` structure for urls, as opposed to the older `url()` structure. If you get this issue sorted, you're likely to run into other issues due to how much Django has changed since your copy was printed. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is the best SO post I've seen addressing `NoReverseMatch` errors. As for this specific issue, it might be an error in the topics.html file.

Comment: `'Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found.` This makes it look like the id for the topic is not being passed through the url. Can you post your topics.html file?

Comment: I know you probably hear it all the time but your book is awesome. Just awesome all around, and thank you for taking the time to help. I have looked over the post and you tagged I think I see where I went wrong. And as requested I have posted the Topics.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `topics.html`. Here's the loop that shows each topic:

```
    {%for topic in topics%}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic_id%}">{{topic}}</a>
        </li>
    {%empty%}
        <li>No topics have been added yet</li>
    {%endfor%}
```

The variable `topic_id` is not defined. That should be `topic.id`, which accesses the `id` attribute of `topic`.

Answer (score 0):

In your template you are trying to access `topic` but in `views.py` you didn't pass `topic` variable to `context`. pass `topic` in your `context` variable:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries, 'topic': topic}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks but the error still remains after I insert the topic variable into the context variable.

Comment: when you are getting this error? are you trying to hit any url?

Comment: yes, I am attempting to go to the topics page and view the individual entries

Comment: please mention the url. how you are trying to view the individual entries?

Comment: are you trying something like this `/topic/1` ?