# NoReverseMatch at / error when implementing a comment option

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to implement a comment option for a django social media app and I get the NoReverseMatch at / error.

*NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(10,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/int:pk/$']*

I have read [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and I understand that it seems like it can't find the url for post_detail.html. I have looked up a lot of similar issues but I can't find anything helpful to my case. I am following this tutorial : https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-social-media-website-with-django-feed-app-backend-part-4-d82facfa7b3

I have tried to change the way I declare my url in urls.py but nothing seems to work so far. I am including the relevent python and html files , edited for length.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from myapp import views as core_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', core_views.PostListView.as_view(), name ='home'),
url(r'^post/<int:pk>/$', core_views.post_detail, name='post-detail']
```

**views.py**

```
...
@login_required
def post_detail(request, pk):
  post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
  user = request.user
  is_liked =  Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():         
          data = form.save(commit=False)
          data.post = post
          data.username = user
          data.save()
          return redirect('post-detail', pk=pk)
  else:
        form = NewCommentForm()
  return render(request, 'feed/post_detail.html',{'post':post, 'is_liked':is_liked, 'form':form})
...
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
...
 {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="card card-signin my-5">
          <div class="card-body">
            <a href="{{ post.user_name.profile.get_absolute_url }}"></a>
            <a class="text-dark" href="{{ post.user_name.profile.get_absolute_url }}"><b>{{ post.user_name }}</b></a>
            <br><small class="text-muted">Posted on {{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            <br><br>
            <p class="card-text text-dark">{{ post.description }}</p>
          </div>
          <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}"></a><img class="card-img-top" src="{{post.pic.url}}" alt="Picture not found"></a>
          {% if post.tags %}
          <br>
          <p class="text-danger ml-3"><b>Tags: <i>{{ post.tags }}</i></b></p>
          {% endif %}  
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'post-detail' %}">Comments | {{ post.details.count }}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %} 
...
```

**models.py**

```
...
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
            return self.description
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
...
```

And finally here is the error trace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'pigeonpost',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template myProject\backend\pigeonpost\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(10,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/<int:pk>/$']
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 :   <head>
   4 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   5 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   6 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   7 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   8 :     <meta charset="utf-8">
   9 :     <title>{% block title %}PigeonPost{% endblock %}</title>
   10 :   </head>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "myProject\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "myProject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(10,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/<int:pk>/$']
```

Anything would help greatly ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem !
I needed to change the way i was calling my url as it was the old way.

```
 path('post/<int:pk>/', core_views.post_detail, name='post-detail')
```

This was the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First, the last  tag has the post detail URL but without the required integer variable.

Second, you shouldn't loop through posts because it is a single object.

Third, according to the view you are showing, there is no context variable named 'posts'.  It's post.

Comment: Thank you for the first remark. 
For the two others, It's because I display them in a list on my page. That is all defined in other parts of the files and work correctly. I encounter this error message only when I try to implement the comment option.

Comment: Also , this does not fix my issue