# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/ in django ()

Tags: django

**strong text**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZYXJ.png)

Reverse for 'auth_password_reset' not found. 'auth_password_reset' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Please Tell me how to solve this error

Comment: Share your `urls.py` where you included the auth views.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the html file, You would have used auth_password_reset as a url, but django cannot find the the url hence it raises the error. [More on noReverseMatch Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Here are some possible errors:

1. You have not given any url the name 'auth_password_reset' hence django cannot find it.
2. If you're using any app_name you will have to include that as well.
   For example:

urls.py

```
app_name = 'app_one'

urlpatterns=[
    path('home/', views.auth_password_reset, name='auth_password_reset'),
]
```

html file:

```
{% url 'app_one:auth_password_reset' %}
```