# NoReverseMatch at /vistaprevia/pedidos/4/edit Reverse for 'editr' not found. 'editr' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a problem with an edit view in django 3.2 and python 3.9.2, the problem is when a get into the link EDITAR in my view, it throws me the error "NoReverseMatch at /vistaprevia/pedidos/4/edit" and says to me that "Reverse for 'editr' not found. 'editr' is not a valid view function or pattern name.", I cant found what is going on with the code. Here is my code

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from vistaprevia.models import Op
from vistaprevia.forms import CargarFormOp, EditarFormOp#, EditarFormRem
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

app_name = 'vistaprevia'

#VISTA QUE MUESTRA LOS ULTIMOS 10 PEDIDOS
def index(request):
    ultimasop = Op.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
    return render(request, 'vistaprevia/index.html', context={'ultimasop':ultimasop})

#DETALLE PEDIDOS
class PedidoDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Op

#CARGA DE PEDIDOS, EMPIEZ LA ACCION, WIIIIIIIIII
def cargar_pedido(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CargarFormOp(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            fecha = form.cleaned_data['fecha']
            cliente = form.cleaned_data['cliente']
            tipoop = form.cleaned_data['tipoop']
            fact = form.cleaned_data['fact']
            condicion = form.cleaned_data['condicion']
            despacho = form.cleaned_data['despacho']
            vendedor = form.cleaned_data['vendedor']
            
            newdoc = Op(fecha=fecha, cliente=cliente, tipoop=tipoop,fact=fact, condicion=condicion, despacho=despacho ,vendedor=vendedor)
            newdoc.save()
            return redirect("index")
    else:
        form = CargarFormOp()
    return render(request, 'vistaprevia/formulario.html', {'form': form})
    
#AGREGAMOS TODO LO REFERETE AL PAGO Y DEMAS, MENS COSAS PARA QUE HAGA EN MI TRABAJO, SUPER WIIIIIIIIII
def editar_pedido(request, pk):
    pedid = get_object_or_404(Op, pk=pk)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = EditarFormOp(request.POST, instance = pedid)
        if form.is_valid():
            pedid.npedido1 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.nfactura1 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.nrecibo1 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.npedido2 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.nfactura2 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.nrecibo2 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.fecharem1 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.nrem1 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.fecharem2 = form.save(commit=False)
            pedid.nrem2 = form.save(commit=False)   
            pedid.save()
            return redirect('pedido-detalle', pk=pedid.pk)
    else:
        form = EditarFormOp(instance=pedid)
    return render(request, 'vistaprevia/editar_pedido.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Op

class CargarFormOp(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Op
        fields = ['fecha', 'cliente', 'tipoop', 'fact', 'condicion', 'despacho', 'vendedor', 'estadoop', 'deudaop']
   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CargarFormOp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   
class EditarFormOp(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Op
        fields = ['npedido1', 'nfactura1', 'nrecibo1', 'npedido2', 'nfactura2', 'nrecibo2', 'fecharem1', 'nrem1', 'fecharem2', 'nrem2']
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditarFormOp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from vistaprevia import views

app_name = 'vistaprevia'

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('cargar/', views.cargar_pedido, name='cargar'),
    path('pedidos/<int:pk>', views.PedidoDetailView.as_view(), name='pedido-detalle'),    
    path('pedidos/<int:pk>/edit', views.editar_pedido, name='editr'),
]
```

op-detail.html

```
            <article class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 tarjeta3">
                <h1>Remitos:</h1>
                <p>Fecha: {{ fecharem1 }}</p>
                <p>N° Remito: {{ nrem1 }}(1)</p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="#">Remito 1</a></p>
                <p>Fecha: {{ fecharem2 }} </p>
                <p>N° Remito (2): {{nrem2}}</p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="#">Remito 2</a></p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="{% url 'vistaprevia:editr' op.pk %}">Editar</a></p>
            </article>
```

editar_pedido.html

```
{% extends 'vistaprevia/plantilla.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<!--muestra por pedidos-->
    <main class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 tarjeta1">
                <h1>Pedido: </h1>
                <p>Fecha: {{ op.fecha }}</p>
                <p>Cliente: {{ op.cliente }}</p>
                <p>Tipo OP: {{ op.tipoop }}</p>
                <p>% Facturado: {{ op.fact }}</p>
                <p>Condicion de pago: {{ op.condicion }}</p>
                <p>Despacho: {{ op.despacho }}</p>
                <p>Vendedor: {{ op.vendedor }}</p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="#">Archivo OP</a></p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="#">Proforma (1)</a></p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="#">Proforma (2)</a></p>
            </article>
            <article class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 tarjeta2">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="GUARDAR">
            </article>
            <article class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 tarjeta3">
                <h1>Remitos:</h1>
                <p>Fecha: {{ op.fecharem1 }}</p>
                <p>N° Remito: {{ op.nrem1 }}(1)</p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="#">Remito 1</a></p>
                <p>Fecha: {{ op.fecharem2 }} </p>
                <p>N° Remito (2): {{ op.nrem2 }}</p>
                <p><a class="light bg-dark col-2" href="#">Remito 2</a></p>
                <p><a href="{% url 'editr' pk=op.opid %}" >Editar</a></p>
            </article>          
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the contents of `editar_pedido.html`.

Comment: done. I recently added

Comment: `{% url 'editr' pk=op.opid %}` this should be `{% url 'vistaprevia:editr' pk=op.opid %}` because you have _namespaced_ your url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: same error but know the description it s different

Comment: Reverse for 'editr' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vistaprevia/pedidos/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit$'] it s now

Comment: I read it but doesnt help or maybe I couldn t understand

Comment: for this problem change back the return that i told you to change on my answer before

Comment: Not, i am seriuosly running out of options

Comment: Well you haven't passed any variable named `op` in the context from your `editar_pedido` view...

Comment: But the variable comes from the previous view, I mean, I have a indexview, a detail view and the edit view which leads to the form for editing

Comment: In the urls.py I tried to change the <int:pk> to (?P<pk>\w+) and now the changed to page not found, it s like a happy misfortune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on `editar_pedido` change the return to this :

```
return redirect(reverse('pedido-detalle', kwargs={"pk": pedid.pk}))
```

Comment: try to use href="{% url 'editr' op.pk %}" on the template

Comment: same problem, i wish I could know more but dont know how to solve

Comment: did you try to restart the server?

Comment: a lot of times. seriously