# In django how In can pass data through URL?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I want to pass the model's *`id`* through the URL. I have created a path and view according but still I get **`NoReverseMatch at /url`** error.

Here's the code that I used in my project:

In **template_name.html** :

```html
<a href="{% url 'url_name' model.id %}">
```

In **view.py** :

```py
def view_name(request, id):
```

In **urls.py**:

```py
path('url_name/<int:id>', view_name, name='url_name')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is advisable to always add a trailing slash to your urls like so:

```
path('url_name/<int:id>/', view_name, name='url_name')
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass path param like this:

```py
<a href={% url 'url_name' id=model.id %}>Click</a>
```

Comment: Actually, I make comment on some stuff without putting model.id, that's why I am getting errors. After removing the comment section, It's working fine.