# Reverse for 'category_2' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, html, django, categories

I want whenever I click on the category,
I can see the available categories and by clicking on each one I can display the products of that category and again by clicking on the product name, I can see the page of that product.
Here, clicking on the category in the first step will display this error. what's the reason

in views.py:

```
def product_detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(product=product)
    offers = PriceOffer.objects.filter(product=product).order_by('-offer_price')
    off_list = [float(product.first_bid)]
    maximum = float(product.first_bid)


    if request.method == 'POST':
    
    #comment
    #offer


    context = {
        'product': product,
        'comments': comments, 
        'offers': offers,
        'off' : off
    }

    return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', context)

def category(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'auctions/category.html', {'categories': categories})

def category_2(request,cat_id):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)
    products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', {'category': category, 
    'products': products})
```

urls.py:

```
path("product_detail/<int:product_id>/", views.product_detail, 
name="product_detail"),
path("category", views.category, name="category"),
path("category_2/<int:cat_id>/", views.category_2, name="category_2"),
```

category.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <h2>All Categories</h2>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <h3><a href="{% url 'category_2' category.pk %}">{{ 
category.name }}</a></h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

product_detail.html(Only the relevant part):

```
<h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
{% for product in products %}
    <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

layout.html(Displays the linked category at the top of the page):

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Auctions{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Auctions</h1>
         <div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                Signed in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
            {% else %}
                Not signed in.
            {% endif %}
       </div>
       <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' 
                  %}">Active Listings</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category' 
                   %}">Category</a>
            </li>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' 
            %}">Log Out</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
    <hr>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/category
File "C:\Users\Nazi\Desktop\test\commerce\auctions\views.py", 
line 128, in category
return render(request, 'auctions/category.html', {'categories': 
categories})
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /category
Exception Value: Reverse for 'category_2' with arguments '('',)' 
not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category_2/(?P<cat_id>[0- 
9]+)/\\Z']
```

Comment: This post has a nice summary of debugging steps you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @Ada Thank you. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Given I understand it correctly, you want to determine the URL for a category. Since there are multiple `categories`, you will need to *loop* over the categories, and for each `category` then use the corresponding primary key, so:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  {% for category in categories %}
    <h3><a href="{% url 'category_2' category.pk %}">{{ category.name }}</a></h3>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: it's run but it doesn't show any thing....

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: well, are there any `Category` in the database?

Comment: @ willeM_Van Onsem yeah

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: does your `layout` has a `{% block body %}`? Can you edit the question with the full/most of the `layout.html`?

Comment: Onsem Although the work should be done based on the data in the table related to products, but the table related to categories in the Sql file is empty.

Comment: yes.Check the question again

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: but the question only contains a very small fragment of `layout.html`, and has no `{% block body %}`. It is not the `category.html`, but `layout.html` since you "inherit" from that.

Comment: All html files inherit from layout. I put the complete layout file.

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: what does it show if you add `print(categories)` before the `render` part in the console. Do you see any data in the console?

Comment: No.It doesn't display anything

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: well then likely there is simply no categories in the database to show at all?

Comment: exists. It displays the products on the main page and the category is one of the product information.

Comment: But are you sure you are triggering the `category` view? It should at *least* print `<QuerySet ...` on the console if you `print(categories)` (before the `return render(...)` part).

Comment: I enter the product information in the admin page.
And there is no need to enter the categories and the program will extract this information from the product information.

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: but it is not about the `ModelAdmin`. You create a view to display the categories, right. Now when you visit that path, it should "trigger" the view, so a `print(..)` in the view that is evaluated, should appear in the console where you run the server.

Comment: Based on my observations, the program goes from the view to the category.html file and executes the <h2>categories</h2> code that I just added, but does not execute the rest of the code And in the console & the elements in inspect do not display data related to this issue

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: so exactly how does the `category.html` looks like, given it has a `<h2>categories</h2>`?

Comment: Hi,The combination of the codes you sent and h2 will only display h2.

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: but your `category.html` does not have a `<h2>categories</h2>`?

Comment: Yes, but I added it myself to see if the codes are referenced to this file or not.

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh: can you edit the question with the updated `category.html`?

Comment: Done.Check the question